# prestashop 1.6 adding product with webservice

Tags: prestashop-1.6

For Prestashop 1.6.1.7
Hello,
I have a section in my site visitors they can express their product (second-hand) with features such as multiple photos, product name, product price, contact the seller, description, keywords (optional) them.
I'm going through prestashop webservice after the form is submitted and record on second-hand product categories,
Categories ID is 994.
I wrote this code:

```html
<?php
$shop_url = 'http://subdomain.test.com';
$secret_key = '9CQEDRKAD5IF8C9FFPP59T7AJSCPIW2Q';
$debug = true;
 
require_once('./PSWebServiceLibrary.php');
 
 try {
  $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($shop_url, $secret_key, $debug);
  $xml = $webService->get(array('url' => $shop_url.'/api/products?schema=blank'));
  $resources = $xml->children()->children();
  
  if (!isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
  {
   $html = '<form action="" method="POST"><table border=1>';
   foreach ($resources as $key => $resource)
   {
    $html .= '<tr><th>'.$key.'</th><td>';
    $html .= '<input type="text" name="form['.$key.']" value=""/>';
    $html .= '</td></tr>';
   }
   $html .= '<td colspan=2><input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="btn_submit" /></td>';
   $html .= '</table></form>';
   echo $html;
  }
  else
  {
   foreach ($resources as $nodeKey => $node)
   {
    $resources->$nodeKey = $_POST['form'][$nodeKey];
   }
   
   try {  
    $opt = array('resource' => 'products');
    $opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
    $xml = $webService->add($opt);
    echo "Successfully added.";   
   }
   catch(PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
    echo 'Other error: <br />' . $ex->getMessage();
   }
  }
 }
 catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
  echo 'Other error: <br />' . $ex->getMessage();
 }
?>
```

this is add_product.php in prestashop root folder.
PSWebServiceLibrary.php in prestashop root folder.

Why not working properly, and how can I sum up the form that the product name, product description, product price.

screentshot attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucbGJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must activate Prestashop DEBUG MODE [Activate Prestashop Debug Mode](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/prestashop-16/enable-error-reporting). This way Prestashop will show you what is the exact problem you are having with product XML. It should be some field that is no passing product validation process because has an incorrect or not allowed format.

Good luck.